# How to use JS's parameters to views.py (Django)

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-views

JS

```
$(function(){

  var count=1;
  $("#btn").click(function(){
    count++;
  })
})
```

views.py

```
def setparam(request):

    counts=range(1,count)
```

eg.

Like this I want  use JS's count to view.py .How can I get it ,is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need send this to server.
I guess you ajax for your example.

**JS**

```
 function send_cont(cont) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '{% url "your_app.views.your_view" %}',
            type: "GET",
            data: {
                cont: cont
            },
            success: function (json) {
                //Something
            },
            error: function (json) {
                //Something
            }
        });
    }
```

**View**

```
def your_view(request):
   cont = request.GET.get('cont'))
   #More code
```

Comment: I have a question, if the javascript is written in a different file, it works too?

Comment: @JesusMurFontanals importting you file on head:
<script type="text/javascript" src="yourfile.js"></script>

Comment: I suppose using the tag {% static 'yourfile.js' %}, thanks.

Comment: when i use ajax url: '{% url  "param.views.setparam" %}',it errors  told me that "Reverse for 'param.views.setparam' not found. 'param.views.setparam' is not a valid view function or pattern name."  Are some where to be set?

Comment: You need add a url in urls.py, see django documentation and try to complete djangoproject tutorial

Comment: My urls.py ( url(r'^$', views.setparam, name='setparam') ),and ajax's url ( url: '{% url "setparam" %}' ),no errors,is that right? but my django get nothing from html